# iOS, OSX: Properties of const DOM elements are immutable

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, constants

I am using const to define a series of DOM elements using vanilla JS getElementByID.

For example:

```
const my_text = document.getElementById('my_text');
```

The properties of my_text should be mutable.

```
my_text.style.color = 'red';
```

Despite the slogan, it just doesn't work on iOS or OSX systems. I tested this with Safari and Chrome.

Weirdly enough it works when I test this on BrowserStack or in a jsFiddle.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):
*The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.*

I created a very simple test page here [atap.geolytix.net/iconst_fail](http://atap.geolytix.net/iconst_fail)

Should look like this:

[image]

However on and IOS or OSX device you will only see blue and red in black colour.

The code for the test page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-family: monospace;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="blue">blue</div>
    <div id="red">red</div>
    <div id="green" style="color: green"></div>
</body>

<script type="application/javascript">
    var blue = document.getElementById('blue');
    blue.style.color = 'blue';
    const red = document.getElementById('red');
    red.style.color = 'red';
    const green = document.getElementById('green');
    green.innerHTML = 'green';
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: The [`style` property uses different names for CSS properties.](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-ElementCSSInlineStyle) Have you tried `white_box.style.backgroundColor`?

Comment: i did... background colour is maybe a bad example. let me change this to text.